I was making an assembly program on intel x64 but I got segmentation fault error
this is the code:
;hello3.asm
;27/06/2024
extern printf

section .data
        msg db "this is a message", 0
        fmtstr db "%s", 0
section .bss
section .text
        global main
main:
        mov rdi, fmtstr
        mov rsi, msg
        mov rax, 0
        call printf

        mov rax, 60
        mov rdi, 0
        syscall

I got after compiling with nasm and linking using gcc on linux(ubuntu) "segmentation fault" I though that this happens if the program tries to access a wrong memory address but this is not the case.
here is the content of the makefile:
hello3:hello3.o
        gcc -o hello3 hello3.o --no-pie -no-pie
hello3.o:hello3.asm
        nasm -f elf64 -o hello3.o -l hello3.lst -g -F dwarf hello3.asm

I was expecting hello world as an output but it didn't work I tried debugging using gdb but it didn't help that much, what I discovered is that the issue was with the printf function

You misaligned the stack. You can fix it by e.g. doing a push rbp first thing in main. Also, do not use the exit syscall directly.

I wrote the function prologue and epilogue in main, and I changed the 3 lines of exit syscall to ret, and it worked, so thank you! :)

but can you tell me why I mustn't use the exit syscall directly?

It does not let the C library do its shutdown things, including flushing buffers. If you are using main you should just return or call the exit function of the C library.
